# Is there any way to group Matrix blocks in the control panel (see image)?

Tags: matrix, control-panel

Sorry if my question seems incomprehensible, it's my first question here so please go easy on me :) !!

I'd like to group the fields in the image in one drop-down menu where, if possible, I can add some description to each block.  So is it possible or do I need to learn plugin dev and create one of my own?

[image: talking about grouping those field into one dropdown menu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin that allows you to organize matrix blocks into groups, perhaps that is worth taking a look at. [pimp my matrix](http://plugins.supercooldesign.co.uk/plugin/pimp-my-matrix)

Comment: I did try the plugin, yes he is what i'm searching but when installed and activated and after grouping my matrix fields he shows them all blank, nothing inside them, any idea how is that just happened ?